# Showing density of descret data continuesly in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to show a discrete set of data continuously in a colored image. I used below code but it shows discrete colored points instead of continues colored background.

```
scatter(xm,ym,[],c/(max(c)),'filled','d')
```

How can I show my data in color (which each color shows different density) but continuously? Could anyone give me help?

For example,

```
 ym=[7.5;7.5;7.5;5;5;5;2.5;2.5;2.5]
 xm=[2.5;5;7.5;2.5;5;7.5;2.5;5;7.5]
 c=[30000;30092;30084;30090;3052;30070;30042;30064;30079;30074]
```

Comment: did u try mesh?

Comment: How should I try it? @MendiBarel

Comment: The problem with using mesh is, c is a 1 by n vector not n by n matrix. @MendiBarel

Comment: the problem with trying it is c is n by 1 vector, not an n by n matrix @MendiBarel

Comment: BTW, mesh output is colored lines, not colored regions @MendiBarel

Comment: I don't think it is a hard question that no-one could answer. Is  the question clear? If not please let me know

Comment: it will be easier to answer if u attach some data to the question

Comment: I added @MendiBarel

Comment: this is what you need? contourf([xm,ym,c]);

Comment: Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent. @MendiBarel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
clear
ym=[7.5;7.5;7.5;5;5;5;2.5;2.5;2.5];
xm=[2.5;5;7.5;2.5;5;7.5;2.5;5;7.5];
c=[30000;30092;30084;30090;30052;30070;30042;30064;30079];
cm=c-min(c);

F = scatteredInterpolant(xm,ym,cm);
ti = 2.5:.1:7.5;
[qx,qy] = meshgrid(ti,ti);
qz = F(qx,qy);
figure(1)
mesh(qx,qy,qz,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','interp');
hold on;
plot3(xm,ym,cm,'o');
hold off
view(2)
```

Bonus:

```
figure; contourf(qx,qy,qz,'ShowText','on')
```

Comment: the outputs axis are betwean 1 and 3. what are these numbers?

Comment: I want xm and ym be the position of c. which means axis be in the range[2.5,7]. Why is x axis till 3

Comment: It works now. But one more question: how can I plot another data (points) in the colored region you plot? i tried this after your code hold on plot(x,y), but it didn't show (x,y) points

Comment: when using plot3(x,y) the error is: Not enough input arguments

Comment: use the interpolant 'F' to calculate the third value: plot3(x, y, F(x,y), 'x')

Comment: I used plot3(x, y, F(x,y),'o','black','filled') but the error is:Error using plot3
Invalid property found.
Object Name: line
Property Name: 'black'.

Comment: you can find this help in matlab document. anyway: plot3(4.3, 3.1, F(4.3,3.1),'o','MarkerFaceColor','k','MarkerSize',20)